# Compound query solutions based on no.of rows

Tags: mysql

I have three table

td_idea

```
|------------|-------------|
| idea_id    | idea_name   |
|------------|-------------|
```

then td_idea_comment

```
|-----------|------------|----------
|comm_id    | idea_id    | user_id  |
|-----------|------------|----------|
```

and td_idea_like

```
|-----------|------------|----------
|comm_id    | idea_id    | user_id  |
|-----------|------------|----------|
```

Now I need to use a query which will order the idea in ascending order based on the no. of votes in td_idea_like and no. of comments on td_idea_comment.

A example to the three tables is as follows

td_idea

```
|------------|-------------|
| idea_id    | idea_name   |
|------------|-------------|
| 1          | Pink Ruby   |
|------------|-------------|
| 2          | Black_ruby  |
|------------|-------------|
```

td_idea_comment

```
|------------|-------------|---------------|
| comm_id    | idea_id     | user_id       |
|------------|-------------|---------------|
| 1          |     1       |     1         |
|------------|-------------|---------------|
| 2          |     2       |     1         |
|------------|-------------|---------------|
| 3          |     1       |     2         |
|------------|-------------|---------------|
| 4          |     1       |     3         |
|------------|-------------|---------------|
```

td_idea_like

```
|------------|-------------|---------------|
| like_id    | idea_id     | user_id       |
|------------|-------------|---------------|
| 1          |     1       |     1         |
|------------|-------------|---------------|
| 2          |     2       |     1         |
|------------|-------------|---------------|
| 3          |     1       |     2         |
|------------|-------------|---------------|
| 4          |     1       |     3         |
|------------|-------------|---------------|
```

I used this query

```
SELECT * FROM td_idea,td_idea_comment,tyd_idea_like

WHERE td_idea.idea_id=td_idea_comment.idea_id
AND td_idea.idea_id=td_idea_like.idea_id

Order BY (SELECT COUNT(*) AS tot_comment FROM td_idea,td_idea_comment
WHERE td_idea.idea_id=td_idea_comment.idea_id),
(SELECT COUNT(*) AS tot_like FROM td_idea,td_idea_like
WHERE td_idea.idea_id=td_idea_like.idea_id)
```

but it returns me zero if in any case either there is no row in td_idea_comment based on a particular idea or no row in td_idea_like based on a particular idea.

Say:

- idea id 1 has 3 likes 3 comments
- idea id 2 has 1 likes 2 comments
- idea id 3 has 0 likes 4 comments

then for idea id 3, the resultant is returned as 0.

While I want it to be sorted as this

```
idea id 1(since 3+3)
idea id 3(since 0+4)
idea id 2(since 1+2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  a.idea_id,
        a.idea_name,
        COUNT(DISTINCT b.like_ID) totalLikes,
        COUNT(DISTINCT c.comm_ID) totalComment
FROM    td_idea a
        LEFT JOIN td_idea_like b
            ON a.idea_ID = b.idea_ID
        LEFT JOIN td_idea_comment c
            ON a.idea_ID = c.idea_ID
GROUP   BY a.idea_id, a.idea_name
ORDER   BY COUNT(DISTINCT b.like_ID) + COUNT(DISTINCT c.comm_ID) DESC
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1e36d/13)

To further gain more knowledge about joins, kindly visit the link below:

- [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)